# How to send data from android app to server and deal with it?

Tags: android, json, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Is there any way by which we can send notifications received on phone to server?

Just like push bullet.

I am developing an app as my college project to read notifications received on notification bar from a desktop chrome extension by using Rich notifications. I have implemented notification listener which already logs notifications text. I implemented GCM downstream and google plus login. I just need to know how I can send notification data to my chrome extension. I have setup google plus login implemented on both side. But I don't know how how make connection between it.

I know json too. I can understand and implement basic things in json. I have some knowledge of developing chrome extensions too.

Help me :(
Your help could save my life :(
i did searched a lot about it but didn't found anywhere to clear my doubt.

Comment: https://www.parse.com/

Comment: can we send data from app to server using parse ? o.O i think it is for downstream only thats why moved to gcm @koutuk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send notification data to chrome extension by [sending upstream messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client#send_messages). To send messages upstream, your app or extension should call `chrome.gcm.send`. You can see the sample code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/gcm-playground/tree/master/chrome).

Comment: will you guide me about GCM Upstream this concept is actually getting over my head :( and project is based on that only :( i can't find any simple tutorial explaining about gcm upstream for upstream i need configure XMPP Server  right its getting for me to implement suggest something

Comment: If you will implement the XMPP Connection Server protocol, it can receive upstream messages from a user's device to the cloud. To initiate an upstream message, the client app sends a request. You can see it [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream). To implement an [XMPP Connection Server](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs), you must initiate a TLS connection. CCS also requires a SASL PLAIN authentication mechanism using GCM sender ID and the API key as the password. The sender ID and API key are the values you gathered when configuring your client app.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me :)  if i want to communicate my app with chrome to receive msg. from app to chrome rick notifications ? then what i need to do ? o.O i mean without storing data we can directly receive  those notifications without storing them in database ? from JSON data ?